# How to read a column cell in Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I try to read whole rows of a given column in listview

As I'm new in C# and use of listview I saw it does not work as List

Below is the code that I use (What I found as solution in some sites)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rapview.Items.Count; ++i)
{
    int idx = 0;
    foreach (ColumnHeader header in rapview.Columns)
    {
        if (header.Text == "Bak. €")
        {
            MyArray[0] = GeneralMethod.GetClientName(conn, rapview.Items[1].Text);
            di = new ListViewItem(MyArray);
            tmpView.Items.Add(di);
        }
        ++idx;
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve 1st column 7th column cells, but I see that rapview.Items[1].Text is empty and similar for 7th cell.

Either I miss something or given solution is not correct.

How to read the value of those cells. If possible with column number by bypassing the foreach loop?

Comment: `rapview.Items[1]` is probably supposed to be `rapview.Items[i]` if you are trying to fetch some data based on the current LV row.  Not sure what the column header loop is for.  Probably also be easier to use a DGV and some sort of datasource

Comment: I tried with more index each time listview give me empty string however in my screen it's full of 26 rows of data even the columns that I look. I use thje column header because I did not find a solution like column[1] or column[7]

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you mean you want to read all Cells in a given Column? Then find the column index __first__ and __then__ read foreach ListviewIten the SubItem[colindex].Value..

Comment: Yes I want to read all cells of one or more columns. As you can see in my method I look all rows of a given row. In this method rapview .Items[1].Text or rapview.Items[0].Text (however the index) returns empty string. Instead of foreach loop directly column number. (ın my exemple they are 1st and 7th)

Comment: `foreach (ListViewItem lvi in rapView.Items)` should iterate all the rows and `lvi.Text` will be the first column text.  I would **not** use column headers as an indicator for subitems: just because there is a column header doesnt not mean there must be a subitem on that lvi.  I still dont know why you are iterating subItems or columns if you are using an absolute reference to GetClientName

Comment: In short if concretize my goal, but it's a part of my problem, how can I read 2nd row, 7th cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a loop that copies every value in the 7th column to a list of strings.

If there is no 7th column in the row it adds an empty string.

```
int column = 6;
List<string> values = new List<string>();
foreach (ListViewItem lvi in rapview.Items)
    if (lvi.SubItems.Count - 1 < column) values.Add("");
    else values.Add(lvi.SubItems[column].Text);
```

Note that C# counts zero-based, so the 7th column is indexed as 6.

You could test the value in row 1 column 7 as:

```
Console.WriteLine("Cell 7 in row 1 contains:" + values[0]);
```

Note that every `Item` in a `ListView` can have its own number of `SubItems`. Therefore we must test it before we access it!

Also note that `SubItem[0]` has the same value/text as the `Item`!

Comment: Thanks. I have to use ListViewItem for indexing Subitems. I was indexing Items of rapview.  The method is very large but ı would check a value of in a column(in my exemple is 7th) and if true add some rows value of rapview to new temporary ListView.